# VBA macro to print Chartsheets to PDF produces cut-off charts in weird scaling

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, charts

Hello beautiful people of the internet.

I am having an issue with a VBA macro I have cobbled together. The macro is intended to format all the chart sheets in a workbook generated by a piece of commercial software, then print all the chart sheets to PDF files. Everything executes properly, but the resulting PDF files show the charts with weird scaling and are cut off on the right. If I simply take the files formatted by the macro, then manually print them to PDF through the File>Print interface, all is well.

I believe what is happening has to do with the chartsheet orientation. The software generates the chart sheets in landscape. My macro changes them to portrait via Chart.PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait. The produced PDFs are in portrait, but the chart sheets appear to still be in landscape, with much of their right side cut-off.

The following is the full block of code.

```
Sub GROUP_GraphTool()

Dim i As Integer
Dim JobNo As Variant
Dim StrWk As String
Dim JobName As String
Dim SubT1 As String
Dim SubT2 As String
Dim NAMEser As String
Dim prnt As String
Dim cht As Chart
Dim srs As Object
Dim SCount As Integer
Dim t1s As Integer
Dim t1e As Integer
Dim t2s As Integer
Dim t2e As Integer
Dim t3s As Integer
Dim t3e As Integer
Dim LED As Boolean
Dim YAX As Integer
Dim prnts As Boolean
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim GetFolder As Variant
Dim sItem As String
Dim chtName As String
Dim LOGOs As String
Dim logo As Boolean
Dim prntr As Dialog


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Asking Questions
    JobNo = InputBox("Enter Job Number")
    JobName = InputBox("Enter Job Name")
    SubT1 = InputBox("Enter Subtitle 1 (optional)")
    SubT2 = InputBox("Enter Subtitle 2 (optional)")
    YAX = InputBox("Enter maximum depth for Y-Axis")
    NAMEser = InputBox("Would you like to manually name each series? (Yes/No)")
        If NAMEser = "Yes" Or NAMEser = "yes" Or NAMEser = "YES" Then
            SCount = InputBox("How many series in each chart?")
             'Getting all the series names
                Set srs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                For i = 1 To SCount
                    srs(i) = InputBox("Name of series" & i)
                Next
            LED = True
        Else
            LED = False
        End If
    LOGOs = InputBox("Would you like to add a logo? (Yes/No)")
        If LOGOs = "Yes" Or LOGOs = "yes" Or LOGOs = "YES" Then
            logo = True
        Else
            logo = False
        End If
    prnt = InputBox("Would you like to print resulting charts? (Yes/No)")
        If prnt = "Yes" Or prnt = "yes" Or prnt = "YES" Then

        Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        With fldr
            .Title = "Select a Folder"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
            sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With
NextCode:
            GetFolder = sItem
            Set fldr = Nothing
            prnts = True
        Else
            prnts = False
        End If

'Counting Title Lengths
    t1s = 1
    t1e = Len(JobNo & " - " & JobName)
    t2s = t1e + 1
    t2e = t1e + Len(SubT1)
    t3s = t2e + 1
    t3e = t2e + Len(SubT2)

'Loop Through all charts in Workbook
  For Each cht In ActiveWorkbook.Charts
  cht.Activate

    'Setting chart print area
        With ActiveChart.PageSetup
            .Orientation = xlPortrait
            .CenterHorizontally = True
            .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        End With



    'Adding Titles

        Set cht = ActiveChart
        cht.HasTitle = True
        cht.ChartTitle.Text = JobNo & " - " & JobName & Chr(10) & SubT1 & Chr(10) & SubT2
        cht.ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
        cht.ChartTitle.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        cht.ChartTitle.Characters(t1s, t1e).Font.Size = 16
        cht.ChartTitle.Characters(t2s, t3e).Font.Size = 14

    'Naming series if selected
    If LED = True Then
        For i = 1 To SCount
            cht.SeriesCollection(i).Name = srs(i)
        Next
    End If

    'Setting Axes to General (getting rid of sci. not.)

        cht.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "general"

    'Deleteing Legend if series not named, Moving Legend if they are
        If LED = False Then
            cht.HasLegend = False
        Else
            cht.HasLegend = True
            cht.Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
        End If

    'Setting Y-Axis
        cht.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = YAX

    'Adding Logo
    If logo = True Then
'''''''''NOTE! Save included logo file to your computer''''''''
'''''''''and set the path to it below where you see hashes'''''
        With cht.Pictures.Insert("##########\Logo.jpg")
            .Left = cht.ChartArea.Left + 1000
            .Top = cht.ChartArea.Top + 1000
            .Placement = 1
        End With
    End If

    'Printing, if selected
        If prnts = True Then
            chtName = cht.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Caption
            ActiveChart.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            GetFolder & "/" & chtName, Quality:= _
            xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End If

Next cht

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated. I have searched high and low, without success. I've found one other thread that appears to discuss this issue as a bug that first arose in Excel 2007 [here](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/676515-excel-2007-11-x17-charts-being-cut-off-when-printed.html), but I'm not well versed enough in VB to be sure.

Comment: When you print to PDF manually, does it print portrait or landscape?

Comment: When I print manually, everything is in portrait. If I just take the ExportAsFixedFormat lines out and print each chart manually after running the macro, everything works great. I just can't seem to print within the same macro as I change the orientation. As if it needs to be two separate macros.

Comment: Well, the forum post you liked discusses the possibility of copy-pasting the charts into a regular worksheet. Is that something are allowed to do?

Comment: I suppose I could create a new sheet in the document, transfer all the chartsheets to that sheet as chartobjects, then print.... It just seems so inelegant. I'd like to become better with VB (entirely self taught over the past few days), so if there is a way to do this without extra nonsense, I'd love to learn it. Thank you for your time and thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... after messing with it all day I managed to find a annoying solution.

To solve the problem, I took the ExportAsFixedFormat chunk out of the main formatting loop, put it in a second loop, and forced excel to display each chart for a second on the screen before running the ExportAsFixedFormat.

So, what is happening boils down to the chart not reorienting in response to the change in the PageSetup.Orientation until each chart is visually displayed for a second.

Code:

```
'updating chartsheets

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    For Each cht In ActiveWorkbook.Charts
        cht.Select
        cht.Activate
        cht.Refresh
        cht.Visible = True
        With ActiveChart.PageSetup
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
        End With
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Next cht

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Printing, if selected
        If prnts = True Then
            chtName = cht.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Caption
            ActiveChart.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            GetFolder & "/" & chtName, Quality:= _
            xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End If
Next cht
```

Comment: If this solves your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark. This is not an obligation, but it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the information on how to be a better part of the community. The UI tells me I will not be able to accept it until tomorrow - I'll do so then.